# ClickOnce Excel VSTO Installation Error - Access Is Denied

Tags: excel, windows-7, vsto, clickonce, office-2010

I have an VSTO Excel document-based solution that I am deploying using ClickOnce to utilize automatic updates. The code is signed by our internal certificate authority which all machines on our intranet accept.  I am running into an installation error for a select few users (most users can install/update from our website that is serving the .XLSX (and related files)) with no issues but I have a few users running into the exact same error.

We are running into the following error regardless if I set it to install from the web or a local folder after you click 'Install':

```
Downloading file:///C:/Users/tharvey/Desktop/OTISOppUpdatePublisher/Application Files/OTISOppUpdatePublisher - Test_1_0_5_0/libs/Telerik.WinControls.dll.deploy did not succeed.
```

Further exception details:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\tharvey\AppData\Local\Temp\1\Deployment\WNMBVH0B.1WD\M89GBL6B.GDM\libs\Telerik.WinControls.dll' is denied.
```

All clients are using Windows 7/Office 2010 with a typical non-admin user account.  I have had them try using an admin account, but it does not make a difference. We run into the same error. I have looked at the user's Trust Center settings in Excel and verified the install location is in the Trusted Location (in most cases, the user's desktop).

Any ideas or have you seen this before? I have searched for this error but nothing has helped yet. What I have found is errors configuration errors with IIS and other publishing issues (which I don't think would be the case as most of our users have no issues) and as such, nothing has helped so far.

Comment: What is the target .Net framework of your add-in? Make sure that you included all the required prerequsites.

Comment: The target .NET framework is 4.  The prerequisites currently selected are: .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64) and Windows Installer 4.5. Set to download from vendor's site.  I currently have .NET 4.5.2 installed and the users that have issues have 4.5.2 installed as well.

Comment: Do you have the Client Profile of .net framework installed on the PC?

Comment: Also as a note, I have had them clear the Appcache using the full CleanOnlineAppCache command from the command-line just in case that might help.

Comment: Let me contact the users to find out about the Client Profile.  That would show up in Add/Remove, correct?  I don't have it on my machine but will find out if they do or not.

Comment: The users do not have the Client Profile installed.  We cannot target the Client Profile as we need assemblies found in the full framework which it looks like they already had prior to installing.

Comment: Update: I have also made a simple hello world solution and tried to install that and it errors out with the same message. If they run the setup.exe with the prerequisites, it runs fine and then during the ClickOnce install, it throws the error.  I did notice the machine is running the Cisco Security Agent. Does anyone know if this would cause problems? Most users don't have this installed and I can't change anything with it per policy unless we have documentation that shows incompatibility. Any ideas?